# Dovecot and SharedFolders

Tags: linux, email-server, dovecot

I want to configure shared folders in Dovecot 2.2.9 (Ubuntu).
I want share folder SHARED from user test to user spamtrap.

my configs:

10-mail.conf

```
mail_location = maildir:/usr/local/office/mail/vmail/%d/%n

namespace {
  type = shared
  separator = .
  prefix = shared.%%u.
  inbox = no
  hidden = no
  location = maildir:/usr/local/office/mail/vmail/%d/%n:INDEXPVT=/usr/local/office/mail/vmail/%d/%n/shared.%%u
  subscriptions = yes
  list = yes

}
```

*can be, that something wrong in directive - location..*

90-acl.conf

```
plugin {
  acl = vfile
}
plugin {
  acl_shared_dict = file:/usr/local/office/mail/vmail/%d/%n/shared-mailboxes.db  # Файл создался автоматом в папке юзера test
  acl_anyone = allow
}
```

20-imap.conf

```
protocol imap {
  mail_plugins = $mail_plugins imap_acl
}
```

File dovecot-acl for folder SHARED:

```
user=spamtrap lrs
```

command:

```
doveadm acl debug -u spamtrap shared.SHARED
```

gives back:

```
doveadm(spamtrap): Info: Mailbox 'INBOX' is in namespace 'shared.SHARED.'
doveadm(spamtrap): Info: Mailbox path: /usr/local/office/mail/vmail/domain.tld/spamtrap
doveadm(spamtrap): Info: Per-user private flags in mailbox: \Seen
doveadm(spamtrap): Info: User spamtrap@domain.tld has no rights for mailbox
doveadm(spamtrap): Error: User spamtrap@domain.tld is missing 'lookup' right
doveadm(spamtrap): Info: Mailbox shared.SHARED is NOT visible in LIST
```

Rights were set through telnet with command:

```
. Setacl SHARED spamtrap@domain.tld lrws
```

I can't understand whats wrong.
Could anybody help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved with tool doveadm:

Here is the manual for the future:

[Dovecot - shared folders](http://www.iredmail.org/docs/public.folder.html)